# Unable to get the value of a text field by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

This is really strange. I am trying to get the value of a text field by id but what I am seeing in console is an empty string. Below is my complete code. All scripts are included correctly.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Awok- Scrapper</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="form">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="query" id="test"/>
            <input type="button" id="send" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="result">

    </div>

    <script>

        $(function () {
            var query = document.getElementById('test').value;
            $('#send').click(function () {
                console.info(query);

            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You haven't even added jQuery.

Comment: You are reading the field's value before the click event, which means `query` variable will hold an empty string. you should put the `var query = document.getElementById('test').value;` inside the click event

Comment: `console.log($('#test').val());`

Comment: putting it inside click event gives undefined in console now :(

Comment: @baig772 i just tried it and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use jQuery you can use it like this:

```
$('#send').click(function () {
  var query = $('#test').val();
  console.log(query);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#send').click(function () {
 var query = $('#test').val();  
  console.info(query);
 });
```

You tried to get value of query which has modified at the time of page load.